# What is the best way to implement remote operation in a .net web application?

Tags: c#, web-applications, client

There is a client application on my server.I made some tasks which can be pause and restart in this application.Now my problem is how to control(such as pause,restart ...) the application through a .net web application?

Does anyone can give some ideas?

Ok,in a word,how to make some tasks through a web application? These tasks(maybe run long time) can run background, and I can manage these tasks through the web application.

Comment: What do you mean by client application ? You are asking how to control your Application from a distance machine using .net web application ?

Comment: there is a lack of information in your post. no, we cannot give any ideas.

Comment: Ok,in a word,how to make some tasks through a web application? These tasks(maybe run long time) can run background, and I can manage these tasks through the web application.